# Problems getting post data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problems getting post data from my view. In my controller i currently have the following:

```
function update()
{
    var_dump($this->input->post('name'));
}
```

That returns

```
bool(false)
```

I have tried

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

but that returns an empty array

Here is my view on pastebin(I can't get the format right here)

http://pastebin.com/zJvuDRu4

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what that markup looks like rendered?  Are your values being set?  Can't tell if that's a snippet of PHP, smarty, or some other framework.  [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can be a great tool to trouble shoot these things, and of course there is firebug... Get you past the $_POST being empty at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the attribute name

```
<td><input type="text" id="name" value="{name}"/></td></tr>
```

The correct is:

```
<td><input type="text" id="name" value="{name}" name="name"/></td></tr>
```

And the others inputs, you have to do the same.

Comment: thanks can't belive i missed it, been banging my head against it for an hour.